# How to do single row selection in kivyMD DataTables

Tags: python, datatables, kivy, kivymd

I am using kivyMD DataTables widget to display my data and allow single row can be selected to do some further edit.
The following is my test case. I have encountered several problems.

1. I use `on_row_press` event to treat the selection, but I found only clicking on the first column will give check box's state change.
2. I use `instance_table.table_data.select_all('normal')` to cancel all existed selections. But the cursor always moves to the bottom row but not the selected row.
3. I found the `instance_row.state` keeps `down` whatever I select or deselect one row. How can I get the row selection state?

Could you help me out? Thanks.

```py
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.datatables.datatables import CellRow

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        id:button_tab
        size_hint_y:None
        height: dp(48)

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "Hello <3"
            on_release:
                app.update_row_data()

    BoxLayout:
        id:body

'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            # MDDataTable allows the use of size_hint
            size_hint=(0.8, 0.7),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Status", dp(30)),
                ("Signal Name", dp(60)),
                ("Severity", dp(30)),
                ("Stage", dp(30)),
                ("Schedule", dp(30)),
                ("Team Lead", dp(30))
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1", ("alert", [255 / 256, 165 / 256, 0, 1], "No Signal"),
                 "Astrid: NE shared managed", "Medium", "Triaged", "0:33",
                 "Chase Nguyen"),
                ("2", ("alert-circle", [1, 0, 0, 1], "Offline"),
                 "Cosmo: prod shared ares", "Huge", "Triaged", "0:39",
                 "Brie Furman"),
                ("3", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Phoenix: prod shared lyra-lists", "Minor",
                 "Not Triaged", "3:12", "Jeremy lake"),
                ("4", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Sirius: NW prod shared locations",
                 "Negligible",
                 "Triaged", "13:18", "Angelica Howards"),
                ("5", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Sirius: prod independent account",
                 "Negligible",
                 "Triaged", "22:06", "Diane Okuma"),
            ]
        )
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        root.ids.body.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return root

    def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''
        print(instance_table, instance_row)
        if instance_row.ids.check.state == 'normal':
            instance_table.table_data.select_all('normal')
            instance_row.ids.check.state = 'down'
        else:
            instance_table.table_data.select_all('normal')
            # instance_row.ids.check.state = 'normal'
        print("instance_row.state:",instance_row.state)


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after digging into the kivyMD, I got the solution

```py
"""
@author:
@file:test_table_check2.py
@time:2022/09/079:39
@file_desc
"""
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        id:button_tab
        size_hint_y:None
        height: dp(48)

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "Hello <3"
            on_release:
                app.update_row_data()

    BoxLayout:
        id:body

'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            # MDDataTable allows the use of size_hint
            size_hint=(0.8, 0.7),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Status", dp(30)),
                ("Signal Name", dp(60)),
                ("Severity", dp(30)),
                ("Stage", dp(30)),
                ("Schedule", dp(30)),
                ("Team Lead", dp(30))
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1", ("alert", [255 / 256, 165 / 256, 0, 1], "No Signal"),
                 "Astrid: NE shared managed", "Medium", "Triaged", "0:33",
                 "Chase Nguyen"),
                ("2", ("alert-circle", [1, 0, 0, 1], "Offline"),
                 "Cosmo: prod shared ares", "Huge", "Triaged", "0:39",
                 "Brie Furman"),
                ("3", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Phoenix: prod shared lyra-lists", "Minor",
                 "Not Triaged", "3:12", "Jeremy lake"),
                ("4", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Sirius: NW prod shared locations",
                 "Negligible",
                 "Triaged", "13:18", "Angelica Howards"),
                ("5", (
                    "checkbox-marked-circle",
                    [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                    "Online"), "Sirius: prod independent account",
                 "Negligible",
                 "Triaged", "22:06", "Diane Okuma"),

            ],
            sorted_on="Schedule",
            sorted_order="ASC",
            elevation=2
        )
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        root.ids.body.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return root

    def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''
        print(instance_table, instance_row)
        index = instance_row.index
        cols_num = len(instance_table. column_data)
        row_num = int(index/cols_num)
        col_num = index%cols_num
        cell_row =instance_table.table_data.view_adapter.get_visible_view(row_num*cols_num)
        if cell_row.ids.check.state == 'normal':
            instance_table.table_data.select_all('normal')
            cell_row.ids.check.state = 'down'
        else:
            cell_row.ids.check.state = 'normal'
        instance_table.table_data.on_mouse_select(instance_row)



Example().run()
```